# Alt Key calling Action Performed Event in Swing java

Tags: java, swing, events

I have an Application in Swing java and m using Manu bar and some of manu in that. but when i figured out that If i press Alt key and that is by default calling home manu. and i have not set Short cut in that.
I have Jmenu in Jmenubar and that that JMenu have Mouse Click event and its not having any Jmenu iteam in that. and its calling that Jmenu mouse click event on Alt.
So how to overcome this problem?

Comment: how to overcome this problem? - by reading official Oracle tutorial [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) - part [Enabling Keyboard Operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#mnemonic), good isn't it

Comment: @mKorbel i read some of that okey i know how to use menus but thing is that its calling its mouseclick event on alt button that is my problem and what is connection of that document with it??

Comment: description is as always vague, there is JMenuBar, JMenu and JMenuItems, have to describe your potential issue correctly, because ....

Comment: @mKorbel JMenu and Its having mouse click event and there is no Iteams in that Jmenu is it okey?

Comment: JMenu, JMenuItem correctly works with Mouse or Key Events, JMenuBar isn't accessible directly,

Comment: @mKorbel Jmenu Mouseclicked is called on Alt okey there is not issue with Jmenubar just with Jmenu.

Comment: there is/are XxxMenuListeners its okay :-), there are a few options, please which one is proper for you, again you don't describe the idea, goal and expectations,

Comment: I posted a few posts about JMenu(Xxx), link my post to your question and with description why, where, how

Comment: @mKorbel well when i press Alt its calling that event now is that not enlugh? :(

Comment: if is registered as Mnemonics/Accelerator, then firing an event, post an SSCCE/MCVE to avoids playing with/if you think that this is bugs, working code in SSCCE/MCVE form is in Oracle tutorial

Comment: @mKorbel i dont get it what u saying :(

Comment: @Krishna can you please post an MCVE? I understand your problem, but not able to reproduce it.

Comment: @Arijit can u tell me what is this MCVE?

Comment: @Krishna its Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example  , see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Arijit bro well i dont have something like MCVE in this because i have not write any code to call that event on pressing of ALT.